# Main will not pull information from the appropriate class. Continues to produce errors

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am taking an intro to Java class and am stuck on my lab work.

We are setting up a class with inheritance. The professor provided us with the `Main`, `Address`, `PersonName`, `PhoneNumber`, and `PersonRecord`.

We are tasked with creating a class `CustomerRecord` that contains CustomerID, creditCardType, creditCardNumber, and creditCardDate. We are instructed to produce a class and make any changes necessary to the "CustomerRecord and NOT the Main"

I went ahead and set up everything for the class but continue to get the same error of:

```
Error:(20, 20) java: constructor CustomerRecord in class edu.cscc.CustomerRecord cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
found: edu.cscc.PersonName,edu.cscc.Address,edu.cscc.PhoneNumber,edu.cscc.PhoneNumber,edu.cscc.PhoneNumber,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Below is the Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize test data
        Address address = new Address("120 North Tulip Tree Drive",
                "Jackson", "OH", "45640");
        PersonName name = new PersonName("Dr.", "Adelaide", "Penelope",
                "Aardvark", null);
        PhoneNumber homephone = new PhoneNumber(740, 555, 1005);
        PhoneNumber workphone = new PhoneNumber(740, 555, 2356);
        PhoneNumber cellphone = new PhoneNumber(614, 555, 9723);

        // TODO - after creating CustomerRecord class, uncomment the following code.

        // Create sample customer record
        CustomerRecord customer;
        customer = new CustomerRecord (name, address, homephone, workphone, cellphone,
            "123456","Visa","4111-1111-1111-1111", "12/25");

        // Print customer record report
        String namerpt = "Name: " + customer.getName().toString();

        String addressrpt = "Address: " + address.getStreetAddress() + "\n" +
                "\t" + address.getCity() + ", " + address.getState() + " " + address.getZip();

        String phonerpt = "Home Phone: " + customer.getHomePhone().toString() + "\n" +
                "Work Phone: " + customer.getWorkPhone().toString() + "\n" +
                "Mobile Phone: " + customer.getCellPhone().toString();

        System.out.println(namerpt+"\n"+addressrpt+"\n"+phonerpt+"\n"+
                "Customer ID: "+customer.getCustomerID() + "\n"+
                "Credit card type: "+customer.getCreditCardType() + "\n"+
                "Credit card number: "+customer.getCreditCardNumber() + "\n"+
                "Credit card date: "+customer.getCreditCardDate());


    }
}
```

Below is the Customer class that I created:

```
public class CustomerRecord {
    private String customerID;
    private String creditCardType;
    private String creditCardNumber;
    private String creditCardDate;





    public CustomerRecord(String customerID, String creditCardType, String creditCardNumber, String creditCardDate) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
        this.creditCardType = creditCardType;
        this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
        this.creditCardDate = creditCardDate;
    }
    //Accesor//Mutator

    public String getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(String customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public String getCreditCardType() {
        return creditCardType;
    }

    public void setCreditCardType(String creditCardType) {
        this.creditCardType = creditCardType;
    }

    public String getCreditCardNumber() {
        return creditCardNumber;
    }

    public void setCreditCardNumber(String creditCardNumber) {
        this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
    }

    public String getCreditCardDate() {
        return creditCardDate;
    }

    public void setCreditCardDate(String creditCardDate) {
        this.creditCardDate = creditCardDate;
    }


}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You're passing custom classes where Strings are expected.

Comment: Your `CustomerRecord` constructor only take 4 String arguments, but you are calling it with 9.

Comment: Yeah, what schmosel said is right on, you're passing your own class objects, not `String`s. Either the constructor needs editing or the call of the constructor needs editing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not supposed to change the `Main` class, add the necessary fields and edit the constructor in your `CustomerRecord` class like the following:

```
private PersonName name;
private Address address;
private PhoneNumber homephone;
private PhoneNumber workphone;
private PhoneNumber cellphone;
private String customerID;
private String creditCardType;
private String creditCardNumber;
private String creditCardDate;

public CustomerRecord(PersonName name, Address address, PhoneNumber homephone, PhoneNumber workphone, PhoneNumber cellphone, String customerID, String creditCardType, String creditCardNumber, String creditCardDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.homephone = homephone;
    this.workphone = workphone;
    this.cellphone = cellphone;
    this.customerID = customerID;
    this.creditCardType = creditCardType;
    this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
    this.creditCardDate = creditCardDate;
}
```

This way, all of the parameters of the `CustomerRecord` constructor are handled.

Comment: `Main` was provided as is (I Believe) by the professor. I believe the OP needs to make `CustomerRecord` comply with how `Main` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Constructor that only takes `String` arguments:

```
public CustomerRecord(String customerID, String creditCardType, String creditCardNumber, String creditCardDate) {
```

You have to make a Constructor that takes 9 arguments:

The first five are `PersonName`, `Address`,`PhoneNumber`, `PhoneNumber`, and `PhoneNumber`

The next 4 are your `String` arguments

Since your Main method has:

```
CustomerRecord customer;
    customer = new CustomerRecord(name, address, homephone, workphone, cellphone,
            "123456", "Visa", "4111-1111-1111-1111", "12/25");
```